# how to build and deploy angular 8 application in tomcat server?

Tags: angular8, tomcat8.5

basically i am java web developer , now i change one old web application into angular and spring boot microservices. i learn basic angular form youtube tutorials and other sources , but i have big confusion on deployment , when we run command ng build --prod ,it compress all files and create dist folder.
i copy all file from dist folder and paste inside tomcat webapps folder and application run fine ,
now i want to know it is necessary to build whole project every time ? and repeat same process again and again when we make any changes on our local development machine.

i try to find the solution a lot search on google but did not get any solution please suggest me what is the proper way for deployment  from local machine to production server

Answer (score 0):

You can use another external front server as node.js instead of embedding the front whitin a tomcat.
with a node.js server maybe you will be able to use the ng serve -o to change files and hot swap these changes easy
Another thing you can do is to set a devops environment, but this is more difficult.